# dynamic URL routing in Django with React

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am building an E-Commerce site. My requirement was I want to change the domain based on user visiting location(IP/any other media). ex: if a user visits my website from the USA the domain should be: domain.com/usa. or else a user visits my website from India my domain should be: domain.com/india. How can I implement this type of logic in Django?

Technologies I am using:
Django with React.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the user's IP to determine the country where the request is being made and redirect them accordingly using one of the alternatives Christian Ternus mentions in his answer for this [similar S.O post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19414530/4905586)